# SQL JOIN 2 tables with similar data from a 3rd table with a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a view to show child items within a parent item(sub componenets of a main unit)
The issue I'm having is when I try to combine the 3rd table, it is taking the ID from the parent table and applying the same price to every field. I have 3 tables:

PGOODS

```
ID------------------CODE
167074             AB4112815(this is the parent item)  
51325              AB4XK103 (this is the child item)
12345              TEST
```

SUBGOODS

```
ITEM------------------CODE------------------QTY
167074                AB4XK103              2
12345                 TEST                  1
```

PRICES

```
PGOODSID------------------PRICE
167074                    23.67
51325                     0.03
12345                     0.01
```

PGOODS holds all of the part information, SUBGOODS links a child item to the main SKU, and PRICES holds the costs of the items.

I know I can reference each of these cells from a SQL statement, but I am looking to combine all of this info into one view, to make the retrieval of data much quicker. Note this would be a one off transaction.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[BoM1]
        AS
    SELECT PGOODS.CODE AS CODE1,PGOODS.NAME AS NAME1
    ,PRICES.PG1 AS PRICE,SUBGOODS.ITEM,

    FROM PRICES
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SUBGOODS ON SUBGOODS.ITEM = PRICES.PGOODSID
    INNER JOIN PGOODS ON PGOODS.ID = SUBGOODS.ITEM
    GO
```

My end goal in this case is to have something like this:

```
  PARENTCODE------------CODE------------------PRICE
  AB4112815                                    23.67
  AB4112815            AB4XK103                0.03
  AB4112815            TEST                    0.01

  AB4112816                                    27.67
  AB4112816            AB4XK103                0.03
  AB4112816            TEST                    0.01
  AB4112816            TEST2                   5.64
```

Thanks.

Comment: PGOODS appears to be the parent table to the child table of SUBGOODS. However, a PGOODS row listing seems to have both parent and child items / rows. Is this so? If so, the table designs seem conflicted.

Comment: Yeah it is, I can't do anything about the table structure unfortunately, I'm lifting it from a 3rd party supplier which is how they organise their data flow, was wondering if it was possible for me to arrange the data in a view as we're in the middle of a changeover of systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE VIEW [DBO].[BOM1]
AS
SELECT P.ID,P.CODE,PR.PRICES FROM DBO.PGOODS P
LEFT JOIN DBO.SUBGOODS   S ON P.ID = S.ITEM
INNER JOIN DBO.PRICES PR ON PR.PGOODSID = P.ID
```

[image]

Comment: This code works fine thanks, but we lose the parent child relationship then, for example there could be a AB112815 with the same child items attached. I think this was my fault, the end scenario I'm looking for wasn't clear enough, let me update question.